# Change the function of a button

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to combine two buttons into one for a jquery plugin called jsort. Click to sort ascending, click a second time to sort descending. I can't figure out how to apply other solutions to this as I am a total novice.

Thank you in advance!
Ian

here is the code (right now with two different buttons):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lut37/22/

```
  //Sort Ascending by year
    $("#asc_btn_year").click(function () {
        $("#demo").jSort({
            sort_by: 'p.txt span',
            item: 'div',
            order: 'asc'
        });
    });

    //Sort Descending by year
    $("#desc_btn_year").click(function () {
        $("#demo").jSort({
            sort_by: 'p.txt span',
            item: 'div',
            order: 'desc'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use a variable to keep track of the order, and flip it each time.

```
var order = 'asc';

$("#btn_year").click(function () {
    order = (order == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'; // Toggle order
    $("#demo").jSort({
        sort_by: 'p.txt span',
        item: 'div',
        order: order
    });
});
```

If you'll have multiple buttons like this, you can use `$(this).data('order')` instead of a global variable.

```
$("#btn_year").click(function () {
    order = $(this).data('order') == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    $(this).data('order', order);
    $("#demo").jSort({
        sort_by: 'p.txt span',
        item: 'div',
        order: order
    });
}).data('order', 'asc');
```

Comment: I think it would make sense to do your second suggestion with a higher priority than the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a `boolean` in the scope, if it is `true`, do one, `false`, do the other, and make sure to change the `boolean` value each time.

for example,

```
var myBoolean = true;

$("#btn_year").click(function () {
    if(myBoolean){
        myBoolean = false;
        $("#demo").jSort({
            sort_by: 'p.txt span',
            item: 'div',
            order: 'asc'
        });
    }else {
        myBoolean = true;
        $("#demo").jSort({
            sort_by: 'p.txt span',
            item: 'div',
            order: 'desc'
        });
    }
});
```